# how do I gardient background with tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I installed React with tailwind from this: https://github.com/altafino/react-webpack-5-tailwind-2

I want to make a bg color like above in the picture. But I get no background-color its white. But Why?

this picture above is from tailwind.com first or second content

```
flex items-center space-x-4 p-6 md:px-10 md:py-6 bg-gradient-to-br rounded-b-xl leading-6 font-semibold text-white from-fuchsia-500 to-purple-600
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fuchsia** is not added to the colors by deafult. Checkout https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#color-palette-reference

```
// tailwind.config.js
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      // Build your palette here
      fuchsia: colors.fuchsia,
  }
}
```

Then, your gradient `from-fuchsia-500` will work.